# Is it encouraged to use an invented root word if I don't like the sound of an existing root word?

Tags: word-choice, word-formation

Newbie here.

I really don't like the translation of the word "horse" into Esperanto: ĉevalo.

Is it encouraged to use your own root word if you think people will understand you?

I love the latin word for horse: "Equus"
I love how it looks like, I love the sound of it.

Would it be okay to use the word "Ekvuso" in Esperanto?
Would some speakers shake their heads and say: "Not again, one of those pricks who thinks he can just invent his own words in my beautiful language. Just use ĉevalo, why don't you!"

Would people even understand that Ekvuso means horse to me?
If not, what if I found a better example? For example, instead Hundo I use Dogo? What about Cano (derived from latin) or Sabako (derived from russian)?

Help me out please. I'm trying to understand the elasticity of this language, and if this is encouraged or not.

Answer (score 8):

I think this would work about as well as it would work in English (ie, not very well at all). I reckon the majority of esperantists wouldn’t understand the word or even if they did they would just assume you are a beginner who got confused about the right word.

It’s not very common to change existing root words of the language but it does sometimes happen. For example there is a tendancy that words containing the letter *ĥ* are slowly being replaced with alternatives. For example almost everybody now says *ĉino* instead *ĥino*. However this is done on a very gradual basis and depends on large numbers of people slowly adopting it. The language is now over 130 years old and the root words are well established enough that the kinds of propositions you are making are extremely unlikely to catch on.

On the other hand, I think it is quite encouraged to invent words using the existing roots and suffixes if it is easy to understand. For example you might say something like this:

> La burgero de McDonalds estas *nemanĝeblaĵo*.

This is a word that could be spontaneously made up during the course of a conversation and it is easy to understand because it is consists of the well known roots *ne*, *manĝ*, *ebl* and *aĵ*.

Sometimes people do introduce new words for new concepts. For example [*memeo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/memeo) is a relatively recent root for a modern concept. However this is quite different from introducing a new root to replace an old root with exactly the same meaning. Some people would argue that even this should be discouraged and it would be better to invent a word using Esperanto roots.

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you. I was raised bilingual, german and russian. Often (very often) we use a german word while we are talking in russian, and we bastardize the german word in so far as we take the root of the german word (or sometimes the whole word) and put the grammatically correct russian ending suffix at the back of the word. For example: "Ya PUTZewaju", as in putzen, as in cleaning, but inside a russian sentence, with russian grammar

Answer (score 3):

Vivantaj lingvoj nek permesas nek malpermesas tion. La kuraĝigo aŭ malkuraĝigo venas rekte el la reago de viaj samlingvanoj. Mi opinias ke ŝato, ĉefe pri vortoj sen sinonimoj, estas ofte lukso de nedenaskuloj kaj, inter tiuj, de komencantoj.

Lingvoj (vivantaj) favoras rapidan, senĝenan interkomunikadon kaj pro tio, en komunumoj kie du aŭ pluraj lingvoj kontaktiĝas, la uzado de pli trafaj, konvenaj aŭ *belsonaj* pruntitaj vortoj estas normala afero (parolantoj tamen vole modifas la *invititajn* radikojn antaŭ ol ilin gastigi, per sonŝanĝoj, deklinacio, konjugacio,...).

Vi eble povas diri `putzevaju` (putze + ваю) anstataŭ `mi purigas` tie kie, pro iu kialo, la rusa kaj la germana kontaktiĝas (povas esti ekzemple pro familia deveno, ne nepre pro geografia/milita/ekonomia kialo). Sed en tiu sama kunteksto lingva vi verŝajne tre malfacile povus uzi la vortojn `dǎsǎo` (mandarenan) aŭ `limpiar` (hispanan) kiel bazojn por miksaĵdevena verbo, ĉar tiuj pruntitaj vortoj signifas nenion por la aliaj. La kontaktregiono lingva decidas, kio estas tuj tie akceptebla kaj kio ne.

Reen al la esperanta; ĝiaj parolantoj estas en kontakto kun pluraj lingvoj pro tio ke ĝi estas tutmonda, vi do devus elekti tre zorge novan radikon, tiel ke ĝi povos esti komprenata facile kaj senĝene de la plimulto de internaciaj parolantoj (en pli limigitaj grupoj vi ja rajtus fari preskaŭ ion ajn). El kiu lingvo venus tiu zorge elektita novradiko?

Ĝi verŝajne venos el jam internaciigita sono aŭ parolo aŭ nocio (la etimologia aŭ lingva deveno gravos multe malpli ola la tujkomprenebleco). Ekzakte tion diras la dekkvina regulo!

Eble multaj ŝatus ke `papilio` venu el [pinpilinpauŝa](https://www.bihotzparis.com/blogs/blog/ways-to-say-butterfly-in-basque) (unu el pluraj eŭskaj vortoj por ĝi). Tiu vorto estas [ideosono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideophone) kiu priskribas la flugadon. Sed trudi ĝin en alian lingvon ... bonŝancon. Radikoj, vortoj, eĉ deklinacioj, konjugacioj kaj gramatikaj reguloj estas parto de la kodo interkomunika kerna kiun ni bezonas por konsideri nin samlingvanoj, kaj tio limigas kion vi povas elpensi en iu aparta momento kaj ĉirkaŭaĵo, sen dialektiĝi.

La kapablo akcepti arbitran elpensaĵojn de iu ajn unuopa parolanto por jam establita nocio ne estas, laŭ mi, taŭga difino de elasteco por vivanta lingvo.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's cool to note that the Esperanto *scientific* word for genus/species of horse is already out there: "Ekvo", "Ekvedoj", and so on:

- https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ekvo
- https://vortaro.net/#ekvo_kd

But in general, if you use that, people won't know what you're talking about. It's probably better to use ĉevalo if you desire to be understood.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it encouraged to use your own root word if you think people will
> understand you?

Normally, new roots should enter the language only if they satisfy the 15th rule ([Fundamento de Esperanto / Grammar - Vikifontaro](https://eo.wikisource.org/wiki/Fundamento_de_Esperanto/Grammar)):

> 15. The so-called "foreign" words, i. e. words which the greater number of
>     languages have derived from the same source, undergo no change in the
>     international language, beyond conforming to its system of
>     orthography. — Such is the rule with regard to primary words,
>     derivatives are better formed (from the primary word) according to the
>     rules of the international grammar, e. g. teatr'o, "theatre", but
>     teatr'a, "theatrical", (not teatrical'a), etc.

If every Esperanto speaker of the international community would be encouraged to use their own root for well established words such as *ĉevalo*, we would have a pretty thick and ever growing vocabulary that would endanger the language simplicity and understandability.